# Why did he use "looking" word in this situation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, infinitives

I was watching Sky news live and the journalist said:

> "And now, it's time for **looking** the weather".

I would have said:

> "And now, it's time for **look** the weather".

Using look **in infinitive form**.

**Could you explain me the reason for "looking" word in that situation?** I looked for some grammar rule for that but I did not find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatically incorrect.

It should either be

> "And now, it's time for looking **at** the weather". (a bit uncommon but correct)

or

> "And now, it's time **to** look **at** the weather".

Answer (score 1):

"For" is hardly ever followed by a bare infinitive.  It nearly always requires a gerund.

> This book is for making notes.
>
> It is time for eating dinner.

However, that use is slightly strange:

> It is time to eat dinner.
>
> It is time to look at the weather.

Would be more common in most contexts.